# Jquery Shrinking Image

Tags: jquery

plz consider the code below:

```
$(function() {
 $('a').hover(function(e) {
        $("#large").stop().css('display','none').slideDown(1000);
    }, function(){
        $("#large").stop(false,true).slideUp(1000);
     });

 });
```

When anchor gets hoverd the img slides down as per the code but immediately if mouseleave event occur the img slides up but after that when again hoverd over the anchor the img is shrinking in size.Why is that happening?How can i get rid of that .

This is the css part:

```
img#large{
  padding: .5em;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  border: 5px solid #BFBFBF;
  }
a{
 position:absolute;
 top:500px;
 left:10px;
 }
```

Comment: i don't think this is a jquery issue - it sounds to me like a css problem. The code you provided is unable to do what you describe, unless you use "#large" in your css

Comment: @andrew there is a simple css .

Comment: It didn't do that for me: http://jsfiddle.net/CtVGW/

Comment: Is it ok now? http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/4mLsS/

Comment: @nnnnnn i dont know why it worked here.